# Prevented from running Bitcoin Core on macOS

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, installation

When I install and attempt to use Bitcoin Core I receive the following error:

“Bitcoin Core” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.

Currently, my OS are up to date and Bitcoin Core version I'm using is 23.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't that prompt allow you to edit your security settings?

You can go into security settings-> general and enable software from "App store and identified developers".

If I'm not correct a simple search on google will find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Thanks for the helps. It was a matter of opening the app through the applications folder within finder. That would allow an option to open anyway.